# Android: How to get seekbar to work while music is playing?

Tags: java, android, seekbar, android-seekbar

I have looked everywhere to fix my problem but i just cant seem to get
it going.

How do i make seekbar automatically slide with song play ?

this is what i have so far.

> ```
> ArrayList<String> arrlist = new ArrayList<String>(20);
> private Handler seekHandler = new Handler();
> ImageButton next, playPause, previous;
> SeekBar seekBar;
>
>   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>       setContentView(R.layout.layout);
>       getSupportActionBar().hide();
>
>       getInit();
>   }
>
>   public void getInit() {
>
>       songCurrentDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.startTime);
>       songTotalDurationLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.endTime);
>
>       mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
>       mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.firstsong);
>
>       seekBar = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
>       seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());
>       seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
>
>           @Override
>           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
>               // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
>               seekHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
>               int totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
>               int currentPosition = progressToTimer(seekBar.getProgress(), totalDuration);
>
>               // forward or backward to certain seconds
>               mediaPlayer.seekTo(currentPosition);
>
>               // update timer progress again
>               updateProgressBar();
>           }
>
>           @Override
>           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
>               // remove message Handler from updating progress bar
>               seekHandler.removeCallbacks(mUpdateTimeTask);
>           }
>
>           @Override
>           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
>               if (mediaPlayer != null && fromUser) {
>                   mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress);
> //                     mediaPlayer.seekTo(progress * 1000);
>               }
>           }
>       });
>
>       spinner = ((Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1));
>       spinner.setAdapter(songAdapter);
>
>       previous = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.previous));
>       playPause = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.play));
>       next = ((ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.next));
>
>       spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
>       previous.setOnClickListener(this);
>       playPause.setOnClickListener(this);
>       next.setOnClickListener(this);
>
>       totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
>       currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
>
>       // Displaying Total Duration time
>       songTotalDurationLabel.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
>
>       // Displaying time completed playing
>       songCurrentDurationLabel.setText("" + milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration));
>   }
>
>   public void updateProgressBar() {
>       seekHandler.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
>   }
>
>   private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
>       @Override
>       public void run() {
>           long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
>           long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;
>           int progress = (int) getProgressPercentage(currentDuration, totalDuration);
>
>           // Updating progress bar
>           seekBar.setProgress(progress);
>
>           // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
>           seekHandler.postDelayed(this, 100);
>       }
>   };
>
>   public int progressToTimer(int progress, int totalDuration) {
>       int currentDuration = 0;
>       totalDuration = (int) (totalDuration / 1000);
>       currentDuration = (int) ((((double) progress) / 100) * totalDuration);
>
>       // return current duration in milliseconds
>       return currentDuration * 1000;
>   }
>
>   public int getProgressPercentage(long currentDuration1, long totalDuration1) {
>       Double percentage = (double) 0;
>
>       long currentSeconds = (int) (currentDuration1 / 1000);
>       long totalSeconds = (int) (totalDuration1 / 1000);
>
>       // calculating percentage
>       percentage = (((double) currentSeconds) / totalSeconds) * 100;
>
>       // return percentage
>       return percentage.intValue();
>   }
>
>   public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
>       String finalTimerString = "";
>       String secondsString = "";
>
>       // Convert total duration into time
>       int hours = (int) (milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60));
>       int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
>       int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);
>       // Add hours if there
>       if (hours > 0) {
>           finalTimerString = hours + ":";
>       }
>
>       // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
>       if (seconds < 10) {
>           secondsString = "0" + seconds;
>       } else {
>           secondsString = "" + seconds;
>       }
>
>       finalTimerString = finalTimerString + minutes + ":" + secondsString;
>
>       // return timer string
>       return finalTimerString;
>   }
> ```

I didnt include the song list and all the other stuff as i dont see
why it would be necesary to put here. But anyways, when i do what i
have here i dont get no error or anything, the seekbar just doesnt
automatically move and when i try to move it manually to a position it
goes right back to 0.

Comment: .......................................

Answer (score 0):

U set `seekBar.setMax(mediaPlayer.getDuration());` where duration ~ 7 digits value.
After that u count percents ~ 2 digits.
U need set `seekBar.setMax(100)` or dont count percents and set progress as is.